# undefined reference to `WinMain' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, visual-c++

**THE CODE**

```
#include <iostream>

int Main()
{
  std::cout << "Line One\n";
  std::cout << "Line Two\n";
  std::cout << "Line Three\n";
  return 0;
}
```

**THE OUTPUT**

```
undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status[screenshot of visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiRDm.jpg)
```

i turned on **code runner : save all files before running** but, it doesn't work.

Comment: It's `int main()`, not `int Main()`. Capitalisation matters in C++.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=undefined+reference+to+WinMain

Answer (score 1):

The main method is `int main()`, not `int Main()`.
Corrected code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Line One\n";
  std::cout << "Line Two\n";
  std::cout << "Line Three\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!